# GDAL 3.0.4 invalid coordinate transformation result via ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm using command

```
ogr2ogr -f GML -s_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=neu +wktext" -t_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=enu +wktext" ./file.gml ./file.shp
```

to transform file format and change long/lat order to lat/long order.
GDAL 2.2.3 works fine, but GDAL 3.0.4 doesn't change the order.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The coordinate system support in Proj library has changed very much since Proj 4 that your older GDAL is using. But do you really mean that you have as an input a shapefile with latitude-longitude coordinates (axis=neu)? Have you tried simply `ogr2ogr -f GML output.gml input.shp` maybe with `-s_srs epsg:4326` if that is not recognized automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a knowing issue from GDAL 3 at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546

In that post, has a way to try fix in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546#issuecomment-616344351